# Cannot understand use of files.photo.path and files.photo.type in given code

Tags: node.js

1.what does it mean by files.photo.path and files.photo.type??how to get access of type and path
of user sent photo??

```
        

      if(files.photo)//for photo & file.photo means user sent photo
            {
                product.photo.data=fs.readFileSync(files.photo.path)
                product.photo.contentType=files.photo.type
            }


//schema is-
    const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
      
       ....
       ....
      photo:{
        data:Buffer,
        contentType:String
      },
      ....
      ....
    },
    {timestamps:true}
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `files.photo.path` will give you the exact path of the respective file (where that respective file is located or stored)
and `files.photo.type` will give you the content type of that particular file (the type of file it is - image, pdf, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation recommends **.filepath** instead of **.path** for this particular problem:

```
product.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(files.photo.filepath);
        product.photo.contentType = files.photo.type;
```